# IOS, how to remove the layer one time only on CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation

i have modified [this code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ReplicatorDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009049) to the code as shown below. I am using touch events to trigger the function below to run the animation. The results I am trying to achieve is: every time I touch 1 time, the image layer remove just processes 1 time. The problem I am facing is when I set `removedOnCompletion` to `YES`, whatever the layer just feels like it has removed 1 time but it is never removed, so the program is stuck on same layer. If I keep  `removedOnCompletion` as `NO`, then image layer will auto remove all the layers.

So, how I can make sure that every time the process removes just 1 Image layer? Any help is appreciated.

```
-(void)animate:(id)sender {
//Dont implicitly animate the delay change
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

//Reset the replicator delays to their origonal values
imageLayer.instanceDelay = X_TIME_DELAY;
//Re-enable the implicit animations
[CATransaction setDisableActions:NO];

//Create the transform matrix for the animation

//Move forward 1000 units along z-axis
CATransform3D t = CATransform3DMakeTranslation( -500, -500, 1000);

//Rotate Pi radians about the axis (0.7, 0.3, 0.0)
t = CATransform3DRotate(t, M_PI, 0.7, 0.3, 0.0);
//Scale the X and Y dimmensions by a factor of 3
t = CATransform3DScale(t, 0.5, 0.5, 1);

//Transform Animation
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: t];
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
[subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];

//Opacity Animation
animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
[subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];
stuckfile = NO;
}
```

Comment: what does this have to do with Xcode? Wouldn't the question be the same if you used another IDE? This is an API question...

Comment: just found out use wrong layer. Before use CAReplicatorLayer, after change to CALayer, able to work it out already.